# Running Windows 10: Can't delete a 700 MB file; tried everything

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I have tried every technique I have found, including using Eraser, and nothing has worked. In the latest attempt I changed to the directory containing the file in Command Prompt, running as an administrator, and entered: TYPE nul > "DSC00138_13.arw.xmp BW-LAB.tif". Nothing happens; the cursor drops down to the next line and just blinks. The idea is to turn the file into a zero-byte file so it can be deleted. That has worked in the past. Restarting Command Prompt and trying to delete the file produces the same result: a blinking cursor.

I've already tried Safe Mode, sfc /scannow, and IObit Unlocker.

Comment: Try Unlocker (MajorGeeks). That has always worked for me.

Comment: Well, are you sure that's the actual file name? Did you copy and paste it into your question? The blank space you give is a proper blank space (ASCII code 32), but potentially it could be a number of other Unicode code points ... was this file created inside Windows or, as an example, from Linux or macOS (or resides on a Samba share)? The reason I ask because the Win32 APIs quickly get unhappy with trailing dots in file names or other characters. There is a discrepancy between what NTFS deems valid and what the Win32 subsystem is able to handle (without going through hoops).

Comment: IObit Unlocker reports that it is not locked.

Comment: I named the file, and I used a space.

Comment: Try using the Sysinternals tool movefile to set it up as PFRO so it gets removed on boot. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pendmoves

Comment: I downloaded movefile and clicked on it to install/run?, and opened Powershell and tried running the command as the example showed, but the command wasn't recognized. So I tried it in Command Prompt; same message. I probably am not using it correctly.

Comment: If you have a Linux distro on a USB stick, use it to boot the PC and try deleting the file.

Comment: I moved movefile.exe into System32 and ran the command at a command prompt. I received a message describing what movefile did, so I took it that at the next boot, my file would be deleted. Rebooted, but it was still with me. Did I run movefile correctly?

Comment: Linux distro would have a learning curve of unknown, to me, proportion, but may be necessary.

Comment: Download the trial, make the boot usb, boot from it and delete  the folder using the file manager>>>https://www.lsoft.net/bootdisk/

Comment: I did something wrong when I ran movefile. I ran it again and checked with pendmoves. Rebooted and the file was gone. Thanks for all the responses. I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: @BillMartz - Thanks for the feedback, given your comment I have added this as an answer (expanding on the details) as it may help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

movefile from Sysinternals did the job, when I ran it correctly. Thanks to HelpingHand for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try free [LockHunter](https://lockhunter.com/) or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/lockhunter/). For LockHunter:

- Install LockHunter.
- Open Windows *Explorer* to the file location.
- Right-click on the file.
- Select *What's locking this file?*
- Click on on the *Delete it!* button.

If the file cannot be *immediately* deleted, the application can schedule deletion after reboot.

Answer (score 1):

The most common reasons a file cannot be removed are:

- The permissions on the file prohibit the user/process from deleting the file.
- The file is being held open by a process.

One option that potentially eliminates both of these is to have the Windows Session Manager (SMSS.EXE) remove or rename the file at system start-up. This can be achieved using the PendingFileRenameOperations (PFRO) registry key. The operation runs under the context of Local System and runs early enough at boot that the file hasn't been opened by a process that may lock the file.

This is often used by installers to guarantee files can be replaced or removed where existing files are in use.

The PendingFileRenameOperations MULTI_SZ registry value in question can be found under the following key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager

The following screenshot is an example where four items are to be removed on the next system start-up.

[image: Pending File Rename Operation (PFRO) example]

The space following an entry dictates that the file will be removed. If there is entry after the line (no space) then it is a rename operation. You can think of the lines as pairs of two entries.

Sysinternals have the following command line tools to interact with this registry value:

- PendMoves
- MoveFile

PendMoves read the above registry key and displays the pending operations and  MoveFile calls the [MoveFileEx](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexa) API with the flag parameter set to MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT.

If there are issues with one or more of the PFROs being actioned at start-up, the log file can be found here: %SystemRoot%\PFRO.log, e.g. C:\windows\PFRO.log.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the file isn't locked at all, but the weird double extension (with a space in the first extension part) is causing Windows to throw a fit.
Putting the filename in "" quotes usually fixes that, but is not always effective.

PowerShell is more modern than Win32 and File Explorer and often can do better.

Try the following:
Start a PowerShell Prompt.
Change to the folder containing the file.
Type `del dsc00138_13.ar` and then press TAB to let PowerShell automatically fill in the rest of the filename.
Then press Enter to delete the file.

With a little luck the PowerShell auto-complete will construct the filename in such a way it can be deleted.